# Saving Variables From Loop To Use In SQL Statement

Tags: php, sql

Below I save $name as

```
//$username is a session variable
$sql = "SELECT * FROM followers WHERE user = '$username'";
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $data) {
          $friendsName = $data['friend'];
          echo"$name";
        }
```

I am trying to save each value of $friend in one variable or an array so I can use this SQL statement below to show all forms of $variable

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE username = $name ";
```

or if I have to make it an array

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE username IN ($friendArray)";
```

So if $variable was equal to 'some' and 'name' the sql statement will find the rows that have username is equal to both 'some' and 'name'.

I hope this makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't.  Use `JOIN`, `IN`, or `EXISTS` instead so you only run one query:

```
select p.*
from posts p
where p.username in (select f.friend from followers f where f.user = ?);
```

Note that the `?` is a parameter placeholder.  Don't munge query strings with constant values; learn to use parameters.